# How to filter nested array from mongoose return parameter query

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My problem is i want to filter the nested array that result only show if value of {produk.transaksi.pembelian} id contain same value of {pembelian} id, here the solved solution of non-nested of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49770257/javascript-unexpected-include-splitted-and-empty-array-filter-output)

the code(simplified):

```
[
  {
    "pembelian": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
    "produk":
      [{
        "transaksi":
          [{
            "pembelian": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb"
          },
          {
            "pembelian": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995914a759325776aab0",
        "nama_produk": "Ea",
      },
      {
        "transaksi":
          [{
            "pembelian": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb"
          },
          {
            "pembelian": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995c14a759325776aab1",
        "nama_produk": "Ae",
      }]
  },
  {
    "pembelian": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
    "produk":
      [{
        "transaksi":
          [{
            "pembelian": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb"
          },
          {
            "pembelian": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995914a759325776aab0",
        "nama_produk": "Ea",
      },
      {
        "transaksi": [{
          "pembelian": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb"
        },
        {
          "pembelian": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4"
        }],
        "_id": "5ace995c14a759325776aab1",
        "nama_produk": "Ae",
      }]
  }]
```

expected output:

```
[
  {
    "pembelian": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb",
    "produk":
      [{
        "transaksi":
          [{
            "pembelian": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995914a759325776aab0",
        "nama_produk": "Ea",
      },
      {
        "transaksi":
          [{
            "pembelian": "5ace99b014a759325776aabb"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995c14a759325776aab1",
        "nama_produk": "Ae",
      }]
  },
  {
    "pembelian": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4",
    "produk":
      [{
        "transaksi":
          [{
            "pembelian": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995914a759325776aab0",
        "nama_produk": "Ea",
      },
      {
        "transaksi":
          [{
            "pembelian": "5ace99d714a759325776aac4"
          }],
        "_id": "5ace995c14a759325776aab1",
        "nama_produk": "Ae",
      }]
  }]
```

my actual solved solution with a **dataFromParameter** variable contain of json(not mongoose parameter):

```
Pembelian
    .find({})
    .populate('dp')
    .populate('pelunasan')
    .populate('supplier')
    .populate('produk')
    .populate('komisi')
    .exec((err, dataPembelian) => {
      var dataFromParameter = [{...}] //copied dataPembelian json directly from browser
      function filter2() {
        let result = []
        for (pembelian of dataFromParameter) {
          result.push(pembelian.produk.map(
            o => Object.assign(
              o, {
                "transaksi": o["transaksi"].filter(o => {
                  return pembelian._id.toString() == o["pembelian"]
                })
              }
            )
          ))
        }
        return result
      }
      res.json(filter2())
    })
```

this is the output actually i wanted, but with mongoose parameter
output:
[image]

my currently code:

```
    Pembelian
        .find({})
        .populate('dp')
        .populate('pelunasan')
        .populate('supplier')
        .populate('produk')
        .populate('komisi')
        .exec((err, dataPembelian) => {

          function filter() {
            let result = []
            for (pembelian of dataPembelian) {
              result.push(pembelian.produk.map(
                o => Object.assign(
                  o, {
                    "transaksi": o["transaksi"].filter(o => {
                      console.log(o)
                      console.log('\nSEPARATOR\n')
                      console.log("THIS PEMBELIAN ID: " + o.pembelian)
                      console.log("LOOPING ID: " + pembelian._id)
                      console.log("THE CONDITION")
                      console.log(pembelian._id.toString() == o["pembelian"])
                      return pembelian._id.toString() == o["pembelian"]
                    })
                  }
                )
              ))
            }
            return result
          }
          res.json(filter())
       })
```

but the output is different with using array variable instead of mongoose parameter array:
[image]

the conclusion of my question is how to filter nested array, and above is i have been tried so far. I don't know why array from varible give different output than array from mongoose parameter. thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Arrays are reference types: `[] !== []`. Also, if you have two questions, ask two questions.